# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'

Tags: ionic-framework, angular8, angular-routing

I created a ionic tabs app, and I needed to change home page.
I did it changing the `app-routing.module.ts` file with this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/start-page', pathMatch: 'full'
    //loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'start-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('./start-page/start-page.module').then( m => m.StartPagePageModule)
  }
];
```

It works. `start-page` is called for first.

In start-page page, I just wanna redirect to tabs page. So I did something like this in `start-page.page.ts` file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
}
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
> URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'

P.S. I did not change tabs page at all. It's the one ionic created for me starting the project.
If I decomment the line `loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)` (and delete the redirect one) the app starts with tabs page without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try placing Empty selector at the bottom

```
const routes: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'start-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('./start-page/start-page.module').then( m => m.StartPagePageModule)
  },
 {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/start-page', pathMatch: 'full'
    //loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
```

As it is a tabs app the below code must be present in app.routing.ts

```
{
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the following lines do not exist in the module file:

```
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
```